# Как задать toggle для стиля?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Есть скрипт:

```
$('.item-contacts__title').on('click',function(){
  $(this).next().toggle('slow');
})
```

Нажимаю один раз открывается его children, нажимаю второй раз закрывается. Однако мне надо что бы когда он открывался имел top: 0 а когда закрывался top : 70%

```
$('.item-contacts__title').on('click',function(){
  $(this).next().toggle('slow');
  $(this).parent().parent().css('top','0');
})
```

Знаю по поводу решение с CSS + toggleclasse однако интересно возможное решение с модификации данного скрипта.

Comment: top должен изменяться у .next()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let isOpen = false; // Задаем переменную в которой будем хранить состояние

$('.item-contacts__title').on('click',function(){
  $(this).next().toggle('slow');
  $(this).parent().parent().css('top', (isOpen ? '70%' : 0)); // В зависимости от состояния задаем позицию
  isOpen = !isOpen; // Меняем состояние на противоположное
})
```

Comment: Спасибо большое